# No known class for selector 'setAutoresizingMask'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

This is my code for trying to put in an iAd but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated because I am very new at using Xcode. Thanks in advance

.m file

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
adView.autoresizingMask = [NSSet setWithObject:**incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'UIViewAutoresizing' (aka enum UIViewAutoresizing)**
[ADBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]];**no known class for selector 'setAutoresizingMask'**
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. You should really read a good C book, and *only then* a decent Objective-C tutorial. You should also read loads of usefulness dubbed "the documentation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto resizing mask has to be set for a UIView instance, not a class. I'm not sure why in your third line you try to add it in a set. This works:

adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

If you need more than one, you use the bitwise or operator to add them together:

adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: So this replaces the third line or fourth line?

Comment: I put in: adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; to replace and the incompatible pointer alert went away, but how do I fix the "no known class" alert?

Comment: @bobsmith, just delete that fourth line.

Comment: @bobsmith, No, delete lines 3 and 4 and add one line of code like I provided.

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks. Now I don't have any errors but when I put the iAd in my .xib file I don't see it as an outlet. How do I do that?

Comment: @bobsmith, in the xib file, you change the class of the File's Owner object from NSObject to the controller class that has the code you show above. Add an IBOutlet to the .h file of that class, and then you can hook it up in the xib.

Comment: IBOutlet and then what?